# Code generated checkboxes in QT-Creator crashes program

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a function who's job is to generate a list of checkboxes based upon the contents of an enum.

```
void Controller::createCheckBoxes()
{
    const QMetaObject &mo = LicenseManager::staticMetaObject;
    int index = mo.indexOfEnumerator("Packages");
    QMetaEnum metaPackeges = mo.enumerator(index);

    for (int i=0; i != metaPackeges.keyCount(); ++i)
    {
        QString name = (metaPackeges.key(i));

        if(!packageCheckBoxes.contains(name))
        {
            QCheckBox* box = new QCheckBox;

            ui->layoutCheckBoxes->addRow(box);
            box->setText(name); box->setCheckable(true);

            packageCheckBoxes.insert(name, box);
        }
    }
}
```

Where "Packages" is the enum containing the packages, and "packageCheckBoxes" is the QMap that is holding the checkboxes for other functions to operate on them, and "layoutCheckBoxes" is a Qt form layout that the checkboxes visually reside in.

Now, the checkboxes appear on screen looking correct, exactly how I intend them too, and inside the layout. However, clicking on them, or asking the code to do anything to them, instantly results in a crash and I can't figure out why. There's no explanation given by "Application Output" other than "The program has finished unexpectedly." which amazingly I figured out on my own without this notice /s

I had checkboxes in "layoutCheckBoxes" before, but they were manually generated from Design, and those worked perfectly. The reason I'm going through this hassle is to allow packages to be easily added through the enum, with various functions performing the operations necessary to generate the required checkboxes and hook them up to their appropriate functions.

The function that calls "createCheckboxes" is in the same source file, as well as the other functions that operate on the check boxes.

I don't have control over the enum, it is what it is, and it's what I need to work with.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if `Controller::createCheckBoxes` is called by the same thread running the UI or a separate one.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is called by the same thread, as the function that calls it is within the Controller source file.

Comment: Use debugger. That will tell you exactly where your program crashes.

Comment: Exception at 0x139fee4, code: 0xc0000005: read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance)

That is all it says.

Comment: No, that is not what debugger says, that's just the program output. Read how to use a debugger here: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html

Comment: I apologize, I've wasted your time, this function was not the cause of the problem, it's calling function was.

Comment: I had incorrectly used an iterator to attempt to access the checkboxes within qmap, and this was throwing the exception. I simply changed the for loop i was using and it worked perfectly.